# Find a subdomain configuration file - Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl

I recently inherited a LAMP server (Ubuntu 16.04) from a client with a bunch of domains and subdomains configured (no control panel). I was able to find all the configuration files but one. Let's call that one xxx.domain.com.

That domain uses an ssl I am trying to find where its SSL virtual host configuration block is because I cannot find it with the others.

I looked in the usual places ( /etc/apach2/...    and  /etc/ssl,... ) using `grep -ri . . .` without much luck.

How would you proceed? 
PS: Server management is not my strongest suit, just one of those a dev's gotta do

Answer (score 2):

A LAMP stack with Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 should have [`apache2ctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apache2ctl.8.html). Finding the configuration is easy with `apache2ctl -S`, giving you both the file and the line where it starts. E.g.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S | grep "443 namevhost xxx.example.com"
```

Comment: This is the closest to finding the file, but  still can't find it.

Comment: @codiiv If still can't find the domain configuration you need to make sure that this domain is really served by this particular Apache instance. Make a request to some random uniq URL on this domain (eg. `domain.com/123456`) and then `grep -f 123456 /var/log/apache/*-access.log` or grep for your IP in the same access logs.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for `SSLCertificateFile` directive in your `/etc/apache` with `grep -fri SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache` and then check each certificate file for CN with `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.pem`